# nim jester how to change static route and directory

Tags: nim-lang

What is the correct way to change the static route and directory jester is serving static files from?

I tried various permutations of this:

```
routes:
  get "/static":
    setStaticDir(request,"./semantic/dist")
```

but don't get it to work.

i receive `404` or `bad gateway` errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes every file in `semantic/dist` available at `/`, for example `semantic/dist/foo.html` would be at http://localhost:5000/foo.html :

```
import jester, asyncdispatch, htmlgen

settings:
  staticDir = "semantic/dist"

routes:
  get "/":
    resp h1("Hello World")

runForever()
```